# how to optimize the python code of staircase problem to work with larger values?

Tags: python, optimization, out-of-memory

I had to create a program for a staircase problem where i had to design staircase with `n` number of bricks. The complexity is that the number of bricks in every step must be unique, and less than the previous step.
for example, using 6 bricks, i can make a staircase with step height `(5,1) , (4,2) and (3,2,1)` but not `(3,3) or (1,2,3) or (2,4)` or any other permutation.

I have designed the code but the problem is that it runs fine till `n` as nearly 100 or 120, but freezes if the inputs are larger than these values. I am a beginner in Python programming and learning concepts on the go.

I tried memoization, but to no avail. I need to know if there is something else i can do to make my code more optimized to run over `n` as 200-250?

```
    import cProfile

    def solution(n):

        memory = {0: [], 1: [1], 2: [2]}

        def rec(max_val, i):

            t = []
            r = []

            for j in range(1,i):

                y = i - j

                if y < max_val:

                    if y > j:
                        t = [y, j]
                        r.append(t)

                        if n / 2 >= j >= 3 and j in memory:
                            mem = memory[j]
                            [r.append([y, item]) for item in mem]

                    else:
                        if y >= 3 and n / 2 >= j >= 3 and j in memory:
                            mem = memory[j]
                            for item in mem:
                                if y > item[0]:
                                    r.append([y, item])
                        else:
                            v = rec(y, j)
                            if v:
                                for item in v:
                                    t = [y, item]
                                    r.append(t)

            if r:
                if i in memory:
                    if len(memory[i]) < len(r):
                        memory[i] = r
                else:
                    memory[i] = r
            return r

        def main_func(n):

            stair = []
            max_val = 201
            total = 0
            for i in range (1,n):

                x = n - i

                if x > i:
                    s = [x, i]
                    total += 1

                    if i >= 3:
                        u = rec(max_val, i)
                        total += len(u)

                elif x == i and i >= 3:
                        u = rec(max_val, i)
                        total += len(u)

                elif x < i and i >= 3:
                        u = rec(x, i)
                        total += len(u)

            return total

        stairs = main_func(n)
        return (stairs)

    print(solution(100))
```

Comment: Do you need to actually generate all the solutions or just to count how many possibilities there are ?  At n=100, you already have 400k solutions, beyond that, the exponential nature of the problem will make it impractical to generate every solution if only for memory limitations.  There would be some optimizations you could use if you're only aiming to count.

Comment: i only need counting, i thought it needs storage to perform counting so i was storing all the values. i have further modified the code, and has updated the code in the question. The time has been reduced significantly, but still, not able to reach the targeted 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach the problem recursively from the perspective of the base of the stairs. The strategy is to add up the pattern counts of the next step levels for each base size.

For example, with 6 bricks, the first call would go through base sizes n = 5,4,3,2 and make a recursive calls to know how many combinations are possible for the next step levels using the remaining bricks and with a maximum base of n-1.   The sum of next levels counts will constitute the total count of possible stair patterns.

At the top of the stairs, you need at least 3 bricks to add more than one level so you can stop the recursion with a count of 1 when there are fewer than 3 bricks left. This will roll up the recursive calls to form larger totals and produce the right answer once the original call completes.

In order to optimize this process, you can use memoization and you can also short circuit the calculation using the base size provided at each recursion.

For a given base, the largest number of bricks that can be used will be the sum of numbers from 1 to that base.  This can be computed using Gauss's formula: `base*(base+1)/2`. If you have more bricks than the maximum brick count for the base, then you can stop the recursion and return a count of zero (since you have too many remaining bricks and will not be able to fit them all over the previous level's base)

Another way to optimize the calculation is to loop through the base sizes in decreasing order.  This will allow you to stop the loop as soon as you get a count of zero for the next levels, which means that there are too many remaining bricks for that base size (or any smaller base size)

Here's an example (using lru_cache for memoization):

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(None)
def stairCount(N,base=None):
    base = min(base or N-1,N)
    if N > base*(base+1)//2: return 0
    if N < 3: return 1
    count = 0
    while True:
        nextLevels = stairCount(N-base,base-1)
        if nextLevels == 0: break
        count += nextLevels
        base   = base - 1
    return count
```

With these optimizations, the function will respond in less than a second for up to 600 bricks (depending on the speed of your computer).

With Python's list comprehensions, you could write this function more concisely (though it would lose the decreasing base order optimization ≈ 10%):

```
@lru_cache(None)
def stairCount(N,base=None):
    base = min(base or N-1,N)
    if N > base*(base+1)//2: return 0
    if N < 3: return 1
    return sum(stairCount(N-b,b-1) for b in range(2,base+1))
```

**EDIT** Here's a version with a "manual" memoization (i.e. without using functools):

```
def stairCount(N,base=None,memo=dict()):
    memoKey = (N,base)
    if memoKey in memo: return memo[memoKey]
    base = min(base or N-1,N)
    if N > base*(base+1)//2: return 0
    if N < 3: return 1
    count = 0
    while True:
        nextLevels = stairCount(N-base,base-1,memo)
        if nextLevels == 0: break
        count += nextLevels
        base   = base - 1
    memo[memoKey] = count
    return count
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.! thank you for the reply. One more thing though, can i use the same without using lru_cache, or without any other library?
I mean if I want to submit this problem to somewhere where importing libraries or modules is not allowed, would something like the memory dictionary i tried to use in my program work similarly as lru_cache?

Comment: Thank you for helping. I ran both codes for 1000 bricks and lru_cache is faster by ≈ 3 seconds. Runtime for lru_cache method is around 8 sec whereas the runtime for manual memoization method is around 11 sec.